# conditional update_all with join tables in ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The following query returns the collection of AR objects that I want to update:

```
Variant.all(:joins => { :candy_product => :candy }, :conditions => "candies.name = 'Skittles'")
```

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
Variant.update_all(:price => 5, :joins => { :candy_product => :candy }, :conditions => "candies.name = 'Skittles'")
```

This should only update the price for the variants returned from original query. Is this possible with AR or will I have to write the SQL? This is a pretty large collection, so anything that iterates is out.

Using Rails 2.3.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @François Beausoleil pointed correctly we should use `scoped`

```
Variant.scoped(:joins => { :candy_product => :candy }, :conditions => "candies.name = 'Skittles'").update_all(:price => 5)
```

Comment: Should've specified Rails 2.3.

Comment: #all will instantiate an Array, and Array does not implement #update_all - boom. You'd want (Rails 2) Variant.scoped(:joins => ..., :conditions => ...).update_all(:price => 5). Under Rails 3, I think #scoped should just be renamed to #scope and you'd be good to go. Haven't tried it yet.

Comment: good point @François Beausoleil. You're absolutely right. I just forget that query chains don't work in Rails < 3 :). Thanx!

Comment: Doesn't work in Rails 4. `You get undefined method 'scoped' for Variant`